# Does a call to a DB spawn a new thread in a method

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate

In class Product below i have a method call to addDetails

```
 class Product{
    addDetails(){
       productDAO.save(productDetails) //Line 3
       addAdditionalDetails(productDetails) //Line 4
    }
   }

    class ProductDAO {
       @Transactional
       public void save(Product productDetails){
           entitiyManager.merge(productDetails)
       }
    }
```

In product class, when control(thread) reaches Line 3 , is a new thread spawned and line 4 executed simultaneously along with save on line 3. OR the thread first executes line 3 and when it is completely done executing line 3 it goes to line 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Only as line 3 is returned, line 4 will be executed.

Indeed, you don't execute `ProductDAO.save()` in a new thread.  Besides `EntitiyManager.merge` is not executed in its own thread either.
So, the call to `ProductDAO.save()` will return only as            `entitiyManager.merge(productDetails)` is returned.

If you wrote a code such as the following, the things would be different and the order of line 3 and 4 would be not predictable :

```
class ProductDAO {
    @Transactional
     public void save(Product productDetails){
       new Thread( ()-> entitiyManager.merge(productDetails)).start();
    }
}
```